# Store data from input in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

Basically I'm new to django world and I'm trying to do smthing here 
I have made views.py

```
def user(request):
original = request.POST.get('originaltext', None)
return render (request, 'posts/home.html', {'original' : original or ''})
```

and My urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from posts import views

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
   url(r'^posts/', views.user, name="home")
```

and posts/home.html :

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Django Project</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>User Input</h1>
<form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="originaltext" />
{% csrf_token %}
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Try" />
<br />
<br />
<br />

<h3>Original</h3>
{{ original }}
```

the thing i want is when a user write something on input the informations stays on the same html page and when he types something else it's append to the list
any suggestion guys ?

Comment: what is "something else" ? and what list the "something else" is appended to? Your question is unclear, show more output information.

Comment: My code does  this 
https://imgur.com/a/zV7aOvJ
When I type something i displays below
what I want is no matter what I wrote in input it stays there and display like a list

Comment: try to use my code below. I am not sure about details, but `original = request.POST.get('originaltext', None)` - here *original* is not a text, but a whole form. you need to clean data to get the text of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this:

```
if original.is_valid():
     cd = original.cleaned_data
     return render (request, 'posts/home.html', {'original' : cd or ''})
```

Comment: No it doesnt work when I put something on input it displays below but when I put smthing again it erase previous data .. thing that i dont want ..

Comment: @Ayoub El Aich so lets summarize - do u want if user provides `FOO` -> we will see `FOO` at the page and in the form, next user provides `BAR` - u want to see `FOO BAR` in the input and in <h3> tag?

Comment: YES exactly that's what I'm looking for
Or 
FOO
BAR

Comment: @Ayoub El Aich so u need to store info that user provided previously somewhere in your project - either in database or in session. Anyway I don't know where this behavior can be desired.